NetSuite Can not upload file in Eclipse Editor
I'm trying to upload a file in Editor in Eclipse, I get the error:
The remote server returned an error:
Integration blocked
It used to work before, not sure what has changed? Any suggestions would help TIA

You need to enable OAuth in your account then delete and re-add your credentials to the plugin in eclipse.

Thank you, I do have OAuth enabled, and did try to re-add my creds. In the end I switched the Visual Studio Code IDE. Thank you for your reply.
